# Java Applet - Stop other threads from changing Graphics color

Tags: java, applet, awt

as part of a school project we have to create a little game using Applets. I'm working on some tests right now but there's one thing I can't quite figure out:
I want to have multiple objects flying on my screen at the same time on my Applet screen. The animation effect is created by drawing the object, deleting it then moving it after a while.

Here's my code:
Robotworld class
    package core;

```
import items.Obstacle;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Roboterwelt extends Applet {

    private ArrayList<Obstacle> obstacles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(600, 600);
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            Obstacle h = new Obstacle((x+1)*100, 100, g, this);
            obstacles.add(h);
            Thread t = new Thread(h);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for(Obstacle o : obstacles) {
            o.draw();
        }
    }

}
```

Obstacle class
    package items;

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Obstacle implements Runnable {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    private Graphics g;

    public Hindernis(int x, int y, Graphics g) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.g = g;
    }    

    public void draw() {
        g.drawOval(x, y, 50, 50);   //Draw obstacle
    }

    //Deleting the obstacle by covering it with a white circle
    public void delete() {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE); //Change the color to white
        g.fillOval(x-5,y-5,60,60); //Making it a bit bigger than the obstacle to fully cover it
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK); //Reset the color to black
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(y < 600) {
                delete();
                y += 10;
                draw();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is the part where I change the color of the Graphics object to cover the circle in white. When I have multiple threads running to represent the multiple obstacles on my screen and redrawing AND deleting happens concurrently, a thread gets interrupted after changing the color to white and draws a filled oval with the Graphics object which color was set to black by another thread that ran the delete() method to the end.

How can I force the program to not interrupt the delete() method between the color change to white and the drawing of the filled oval shape?

Comment: 1. Don't use `getGraphics`, this is not how custom painting should be done; 2. Don't override `paint` of top level containers, in your case, the `Applet` is not double buffered, so you'll end up with flickering; 3. You don't need multiple threads, you only need one (more threads != more work getting done);

Comment: @MadProgrammer Then how am I supposed to move multiple obstacles at the same time?

Comment: Use a single thread, which loops of the list of entities.  Use `Thread.sleep` to control the frame rate

Comment: But they wouldn't all move at the same time, right? It would just look like they are when I get the right timing.

Comment: The time between the "update" and the time when you paint then would mean that they would appear to move at the same time - assuming you're using performing the painting correctly

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that - But updating by looping through the entities means I have to move them just a little bit in each iteration and not by using a for loop to move it from top to bottom because the loop would block the single thread, right?

Comment: Yes. Basically, rather then have a `Thread` for each `Obstacle`, you'd have one, which moved them all, slightly, would schedule a paint pass and then `sleep` for specified amount of time.  It would continue looping until, I guess, all the `Obstacle`s have moved off the screen

Comment: and tell your teacher that applets are dead and to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

## Disclaimer

`Applet` is deprecated, it is no longer supported by browsers, Oracle or the community. It would be unprofessional of me to try and encourage you to keep using them.

I appreciate that this is a "school" assignment, but perhaps it's time your instructor caught up with the rest of the world and started using something which doesn't actual cause more issues then it solves (hint JavaFX) - IMHO

## Answer...

- Don't use `getGraphics`, this is not how custom painting should be done.  Painting should be done within the confines of the `paint` methods. Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for details.  Apart from solving your immediate issue, your current approach risks been "wiped" clean when the applet repaints itself.
- Overriding `paint` of the top level containers like `Applet` is a bad idea. Apart from locking you into a single use case, they aren't double buffered, which will cause flickering when painting occurs.  The simplest solution is to start with a `JPanel`, which is double buffered and which can be added to what ever container you want to use.
- You don't need multiple threads.  Thread is a bit of an art form.  More threads doesn't always mean more work gets done and can actually degrade the performance of the system.  In your case you want to "update" the state in a single pass and then schedule a paint pass, so that the operations are synchronised in a single step and you don't end up with "dirty" updates

The following example simple makes use of Swing, which is based on AWT.  It uses a `JFrame` instead of an `Applet`, but the concept is easily transferable, because the core functionality is based on a `JPanel`, so you can add it to what ever you want.

It makes use of a Swing `Timer`, which basically schedules a callback on a regular bases, but does it in away which makes it safe to update the state of the UI from (this replaces your `Thread`).

By using `paintComponent` to paint the `Obstacle`s, we get two things for free.

1. Double buffering, so no more flickering
2. The `Graphics` context is automatically prepared for us, we don't need to "delete" the objects first, we simply paint the current state

The example also removes the `Obstacle` once it passes the edge of the panel, so you don't waste time trying to move/paint it when it's no longer visible.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Obstacle> obstacles;

        public TestPane() {
            Color[] colors = new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.YELLOW};
            obstacles = new ArrayList<>(10);
            int y = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                y += 55;
                Obstacle obstacle = new Obstacle(y, 0, colors[index]);
                obstacles.add(obstacle);
            }
            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Iterator<Obstacle> it = obstacles.iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Obstacle ob = it.next();
                        if (ob.move(getSize())) {
                            it.remove();
                        }
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            Iterator<Obstacle> it = obstacles.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Obstacle ob = it.next();
                ob.paint(g2d);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class Obstacle {

        private int x, y;
        private Color color;

        public Obstacle(int x, int y, Color color) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        }

        public boolean move(Dimension size) {
            y += 1;
            return y > size.height;
        }
    }

}
```

> But all the `Obstacle`s move at the same rate!

Yeah, that's because you used a single delta.  If you want the `Obstacle`s to move at different rates, then change the deltas, for example...

```
public static class Obstacle {

    private static Random RND = new Random();

    private int x, y;
    private Color color;

    private int yDelta;

    public Obstacle(int x, int y, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;

        yDelta = RND.nextInt(5) + 1;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }

    public boolean move(Dimension size) {
        y += yDelta;
        return y > size.height;
    }
}
```